# 90 Degrees Radial Gradient in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a custom View that shows a (round) gauge. I would like
to make the background of the scale to go from green to yellow to red
(270 degree scale) to black. The problem I am facing is that I can not
figure out how to make a 90 degree radial gradient - to be specific I
would like to draw a gradient that goes from green to yellow radially
in 90 degrees (and then from yellow to red (in 90 degrees) and from
red do back (again in 90 degrees)). My current code looks like:

```
canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);

canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(-135, 0.5f, 0.5f);

paintSection.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
canvas.drawArc(scaleRect, -90, 90, true, paintSection);

canvas.rotate(90, 0.5f, 0.5f);

paintSection.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
canvas.drawArc(scaleRect, -90, 90, true, paintSection);

canvas.rotate(90, 0.5f, 0.5f);

paintSection.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, Color.RED,
Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
canvas.drawArc(scaleRect, -90, 90, true, paintSection);

canvas.restore();
```

and does not produce the required look. Thank you in advance.